# SQL Find duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a table (**mytable**) that I need to find the **master_id** that has both null and not null values in the **value_id** column

```
master_id  value_id
1          1
1          2
1          1
2          1
2          null
3          null
3          null
```

In the above example I need to **fetch** the master_id = 2 because it **contains** **both** null and not null value_id. master_id = 1 is OK

How can I achieve this? I am using SQL Server 2005/2008R2

Thanx

Comment: SELECT master_id
FROM   mytable
GROUP BY
       master_id
HAVING COUNT(*) <> COUNT(value_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`/`HAVING`. `count(*)` will count all rows for a master_id, `count(value_id)` will count the rows where value_id is not null.

```
select master_id
from mytable
group by master_id
having count(*) <> count(value_id) and count(value_id) > 0
```

Execution example:

```
SQL>create table mytable (master_id int, value_id int);
SQL>insert into mytable values (1,1);
SQL>insert into mytable values (1,2);
SQL>insert into mytable values (1,1);
SQL>insert into mytable values (2,1);
SQL>insert into mytable values (2,null);
SQL>insert into mytable values (3,null);
SQL>insert into mytable values (3,null);
SQL>select master_id, count(*) totcnt, count(value_id) nonnullcnt
SQL&from mytable
SQL&group by master_id;
  master_id               totcnt           nonnullcnt
=========== ==================== ====================
          1                    3                    3
          2                    2                    1
          3                    2                    0

                  3 rows found

SQL>select master_id
SQL&from mytable
SQL&group by master_id
SQL&having count(*) <> count(value_id) and count(value_id) > 0;
  master_id
===========
          2

                  1 row found
```

Derived table version:

```
select master_id
from
(
    select master_id,
           count(case when value_id is not null then 1 end) as nn,
           count(case when value_id is null then 1 end) as n
    from mytable
    group by master_id
)
where nn > 0 and n > 0
```

Executes as:

```
SQL>select master_id
SQL&from
SQL&(
SQL&    select master_id,
SQL&           count(case when value_id is not null then 1 end) as nn,
SQL&           count(case when value_id is null then 1 end) as n
SQL&    from mytable
SQL&    group by master_id
SQL&)
SQL&where nn > 0 and n > 0;
  master_id
===========
          2

                  1 row found
```

Comment: this would pick up master_id 1 in the above example though wouldn't it ? - count of value_id would be 3 but count(*) would be 2

Answer (score 1):

Solution suggested by @jarlh is correct and preferable, alternatively you can use below SQL too:

```
SELECT  T.master_id
FROM    ( SELECT    master_id
          FROM      YourTable
          WHERE     value_id IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY  master_id
        ) T
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT master_id
                     FROM   YourTable
                     WHERE  value_id IS NULL
                     GROUP BY master_id
                   ) AS R ON T.master_id = R.master_id
```